# How to calculate the combined volume of selected boxes using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So in my database, one of the tables is called `box` and it has `id`, `length`, `width` and `height`.

[image]

That's what it looks in my website. The checkbox's value is simply the `id` from the table `box`, that later I use to do a `SELECT length, width, height FROM box WHERE id = '$checkbox_id'` to get the variables *$length*, *$width* and *$height*. Ultimately, I need to echo out the combined volumes of all the selected boxes.

But this is where it gets tricky.

I can obviously just multiply the variables to get *$volume* but to correctly assign a variable to each of the checkbox values (in this case, *$checkbox_id*) I need to use **for each**, and that causes said variable (*$checkbox_id*) to be stuck inside it. Without that variable I cant do the SELECT in the database and make that simple volume calculation.

That makes it so that the for each code repeats itself for the number of boxes that were selected:

[image]

**Observation #1:** Sorry and please ignore the portuguese in the textbox/button!

**Observation #2:** *Box #1 in this case has **10 lenght, 10 width and 10 height.*** Box #2 has **11 lenght, 10 width and 10 height.** Don't know if this matters.

That leaves me extremely confused and with no ideas on how to just show one, combined value of the volumes from the boxes.

Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

### ***Edit:***

```
if(isset($_POST['CalculateCombinedVolume'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['checkbox_box'])){
        foreach($_POST['checkbox_box'] as $checkbox_id) {

            $volumequery = "SELECT SUM (length * width * height) AS volume FROM box WHERE id = '$checkbox_id';";
            $query = $mysqli->query($volumequery);
            $list = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $volumeBoxes = $list['volume'];

            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>The volume of the box is: $volumeBoxes.</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the code I have. Still getting repetead results.

Comment: could you not calculate the volume in the query before you render the boxes?

Comment: @RamRaider I'll try that and see if I run into any problems.

Comment: Can you please post some code so we can see where you're at?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Will edit the question right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would

```
SELECT SUM (length * width * height) AS volume FROM box WHERE id =  '$checkbox_id'
```

do what you need ?

Comment: Hi Ian - apologies if I've misunderstood you, but if you just want to show one combined value of the box volumes, wouldn't you just declare `$total_volume = 0;` outside the `foreach` loop, then the line `$total_volume = $total_volume + $volumeBoxes;` inside the loop, and then print out `$total_volume` once you have exited the `foreach` loop? But as I said, perhaps I have misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey, this works nicely but my problem at the moment is that the <div> that shows the end result keeps getting repeated by the foreach loop. And I see no other way to do the calculations without the foreach loop.

 [how the code looks](http://puu.sh/jEUcC/cc59481594.png)
 || [result](http://puu.sh/jEUf0/f87b48931e.png)

Comment: Move the `div` outside the `foreach` loop and substitute `$total_volume` for `$volumeBoxes` e.g. `echo "<div class='alert alert success' role='alert'>The total volume of the boxes is $total_volume</div>";`